# Change a class constructor depending on other parameters

Tags: java, uml

I am doing an UML diagram for my Java Application, and I came across with the following doubt:

I have a class called Information, its attributes depends on what kind of `Node` it is.

For example:

If `Node = TrafficLight`, Information will contain the color of the light.
But if `Node = Signal`, it will contain the maximum speed.

How can I implement that, both in UML and code?

---

Thank you all for your answers, I will try some of them and I will post the solution!

Comment: Which uml diagram are you developing: class diagram, sequence diagram, etc.?

Comment: How about using a Factory class depending on Node Type?

Comment: If `TrafficLight` and `Signal` are both classes, you can overload the constructors. Besides that, you would have to do a switch or some if statements to handle them in a single constructor.

Comment: class diagram @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Well, a possible solution would be having `Node node` attribute in your `Information` class and a method `getNodeInfo`. Then, your `TrafficLight` and `Signal` classes will inherit from `Node` and implement the `getNodeInfo` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that Node is a child of the Information object. In this case, you would need an object for each of the possible outcomes which Node could be. The best way I can explain this is...

```
package.name.Node
  |
  |_package.name.Node.Information
     |
     |_Information.TrafficLight(String color)
     |
     |
     |_Information.Signal(Double speed)
```

I hope that helps. Keep in mind that I've not programmed in Java in a long while but I happened across this and remembered doing something similar in college ^_^; since it's just UML you should be able to get an idea of where to go with your project from his, assuming I'm not just making a fool of myself. Like I said, just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke method overloading on constructors in java.

```
public class myClass{
    public myClass(){
       //do something
    }
    public myClass(String someInput){
        this.someInput=someInput;     
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what I finally did:

Create a method called addNode(nodeType)

```
addNode(nodeType){

   switch (nodeType){
      case trafficlight:
         new TrafficLight //call one constructor
      case signal:
         new Signal //call other constructor
   }  
}
```

Thanks for your help!